# About 'I didn't think'

Tags: tense, exam-questions

In my exercise book, I have a question as follows:

> Come on in, Peter, I want to show you something.
>   Oh, how nice of you! I ____ you _____ to bring me a gift.
>
> A. didn't think, were going
>   B.hadn't thought, were going
>   C.never think, are going
>   D.never thought, were going

The reference answer is D.

I wonder why A is not wrong and why the answer has to be D. I think there should be more than one answer that is both grammatically and semantically right in this context. All can be acceptable except C.

Comment: I do not think this question can be answered. All four are grammatical although C makes little sense. A and D have identical meanings. B expresses a similar but slightly different meaning. As far as I can see, You need extra information to choose which of A, B, or D is most appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your help Jeff. There is no extra info and I believe in your grammatical intuition as a native speaker of English.

Comment: Even C could work with a few extra words: _I never think you are going to bring me a gift, but you always do._ I, too, think A sounds a little better than D, but I suppose D could be considered "correct" if the unit was teaching about, say, how to use hyperbole to express surprise.